# Import .py functions from Github into PyCharm

Tags: python, github, pycharm, python-import

I'm completely new to PyCharm and Python, so I might get some terminology wrong.

I'd like to use a few .py functions (which a colleague of mine prepared) in my program in PyCharm.
These functions are stored on GitHub. In a demo, which is stored in the same repo, she was able to simply import them with

import function_name

I've already cloned the repo to an external hard drive (I don't have any free space left on my machine). But even after searching this forum for solutions, I wasn't able to figure out how to import them into my program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The repo needs to be added to your path

Comment: And you can only import modules/namespaces instead of functions.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide an answer to your Question:
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
You can then set the absolute path to the files you want to import.
Hope I could help you out.

Comment: That's for dynamic imports